# How can I use a variable inside OPENQUERY (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have this query, however it gives me Incorrect syntax near '+'..

How can I fix that?
I'm using SSMS To openquery a POSTGRESQL DB

```
   -- Pre_final
DECLARE @TSQL varchar(8000), @VAR VARCHAR(5)
SELECT  @VAR = (SELECT (SELECT LEFT(RIGHT(DB_NAME(),5),2)))

SELECT 
 a.COUNTRY_CODE                                                                        [COUNTRY_CODE]
,a.COD_CATALOG_SIMPLE                                                                  [COD_CATALOG_SIMPLE]
,a.VISIBILITY                                                                          [Product is Live]
,a.ORIGINAL_PRICE                                                                      [Original Price]
,a.SELLING_PRICE                                                                       [Selling Price]
,a.COST_PRICE                                                                          [Cost Price Excl VAT]
,CAST(JSON_VALUE([tax_class],'$.percentage') AS FLOAT)/100                             [Tax %]
,COST_PRICE * CAST(JSON_VALUE([tax_class],'$.percentage') AS FLOAT)/100                [Tax Amount]
,COST_PRICE * (COST_PRICE * CAST(JSON_VALUE([tax_class],'$.percentage') AS FLOAT)/100) [Cost Price Incl VAT]

INTO #pre 
FROM OPENQUERY(bigdata_hive, 'SELECT
 cod_country                               AS COUNTRY_CODE 
,CONCAT(t.cod_country,''_'',t.simple_id)   AS COD_CATALOG_SIMPLE
,IF(t.simple_is_visible = TRUE, 1, 0)      AS VISIBILITY
,t.simple_prices_price                     AS ORIGINAL_PRICE
,t.simple_prices_special_price             AS SELLING_PRICE
,t.simple_prices_cost                      AS COST_PRICE
,t.simple_tax_class                        AS TAX_CLASS
FROM jumia_datalake.ecommerce_bob_product_simple t
WHERE cod_country = ''''' + @VAR + '''''''
LIMIT 10')a

SELECT * FROM #pre
```

Comment: There are so many errors, where to start? But the + is used for math, and for text you need pipes || to concat. The function concat() could also be used. But for now I would like to advise you open the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/index.html

Comment: Hello Frank,
The only potential error that I see in the query is on the WHERE Clause. 
Can you suggest some solution to bring a variable inside the openquery?

Comment: Ah, now I see, this from SQL Server (and it's valid syntax) to PostgreSQL. IF is not valid SQL, that will fail and you might have issues with UPPER case when you get the results back. But that's something you have to test.

Comment: The IF runs ok, the only thing that I want to clear is how to pass a variable from sql server inside this openquery? Any idea?

Comment: When IF(t.simple_is_visible = TRUE, 1, 0) doesn't result in an error on PostgreSQL, you must have created a function like this. It's not standard. How SQL Server handles variables, I have no idea

Comment: See [Migrate Your Mindset](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/migrate-your-mindset/).